# Extracting a string using regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to extract a string 'MT/23232' I have written the below code, but
it's not working, Can any one help me here?

```
'Policy created with MT/1212'
'Policy created with MT/121212'
'Policy created with MT/21212121212'
```

I have written this code

msg="MT/33235"
 id = msg.scan(/MT/\d+/\d+/)[0]

But it's not working for me, Can any one help me to extract this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the forward slash which exists next to `MT` in your regex and you don't need to have a forward slash after `\d+` . And also i suggest you to add a lookbehind, so that you get a clean result. `(?<=\s)` Positive lookbehind which asserts that the match must be preceded by a space character.

```
msg.scan(/(?<=\s)MT\/\d+/)[0]
```

If you don't care about the preceding character then the below regex would be fine.

```
msg.scan(/MT\/\d+/)[0]
```

**Example:**

```
> msg = 'Policy created with MT/21212121212'
=> "Policy created with MT/21212121212"
> msg.scan(/(?<=\s)MT\/\d+/)[0]
=> "MT/21212121212"
> msg.match(/(?<=\s)MT\/\d+/)[0]
=> "MT/21212121212"
```

Comment: hi Avinash thanks, but why are you using scan, you could have used STring#[], right?

Comment: to do a single match, `match` function would be enough.

Comment: Yes, But what I am saying is, you could have written the code like puts msg[/MT\/\d+/] rather than scan function,Isn't it? because it always returns the first value.

Comment: i don't know how scan func returns only the first value. scan is used to do a global match.

Comment: sorry, I meant to say scan()[0]

Comment: then remove the index part `[0]` . Scan returns the list of matched strings. You're welcome.

Comment: OK, Thank you. I would do it.

Comment: hi, What's the reason you have used '(?<=\s)' ?

Comment: `(?<=\s)` called positive lookbehind, which asserts that the match must be preceded by a space character. So in our case, it matches the `MT/21212121212` part because  it's preceded by a space character. The above regex won't match this `fooMT/444` because the `MT` part is not preceded by a space.

Comment: /s part is clear, but what about (?<=)? why we are giving this?

Comment: I already explained. `(?<=)` is used for condition checking purpose.

Answer (score 1):

```
your_string.scan(/\sMT.*$/).last.strip
```

If your required substring can be anywhere in the string, then:

```
your_string.scan(/\bMT\/\d+\b/).last.strip # "\b" is for word boundaries
```

Or you can specify the acceptable digits this way:

```
your_string.scan(/\bMT\/[0-9]+\b/).last.strip
```

Lastly, if the string format is going to remain as you specified, then:

```
your_string.split.last
```

Comment: Mark the answer as selected if it answers your question.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, is there any button named 'selected' which I need to click?

Comment: "your_string.split('Policy created with ').last" I can't use this one, because that string may appear at any place, it may appear in the middle as well.

Comment: You haven't answered the question: why the OP's code doesn't work.

Comment: I think I have. The OP asked `Can any one help me to extract this string?`. Also, I'm sure that after looking at my response, the OP has learned what was wrong in his regex.